# Twig Link Macro?

Tags: theming, 8

I was looking at various Drupal core Twig templates to get an idea of how menus are rendered; I came across this line in [menu--toolbar.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21stable%21templates%21navigation%21menu--toolbar.html.twig/8).

```
{{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
```

Is `link` a macro? If so, where is it defined?

It doesn't appear to be a Twig [feature](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation). I couldn't find it by searching in the Drupal 8 code base.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a [`Twig_SimpleFunction`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21twig%21twig%21lib%21Twig%21SimpleFunction.php/class/Twig_SimpleFunction/8.2.x) extension, rather than a macro. It's registered with Twig in [`\Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension::getFunctions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21TwigExtension.php/function/TwigExtension%3A%3AgetFunctions/8).

Its callback method is [`\Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension::getLink()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Template%21TwigExtension.php/function/TwigExtension%3A%3AgetLink/8).

Comment: The Twig SimpleFunction link goes nowhere. 